# Python adding multiple excel sheet into the same pdf

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am using Ubuntu 16.0.4. After reading from an excel file, I am trying to add multiple excel sheet to a pdf file.

```
df = pd.read_excel(excel_name, sheet_name = 'Sheet1')
df = df.dropna(axis = 1, how='all')
df = df.dropna(how='all')
df.to_html("file.html")

pdf_name = name_of_file + '.pdf'
pdfkit.from_file("file.html", pdf_name)
```

How can I add another excel sheet from the same excel file to the same pdf file without overwriting the previous sheet that is in the pdf?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the two sheets have the same data structure (columns and etc.):

```
df1 = pd.read_excel(excel_name, sheet_name = 'Sheet1')
df2 = pd.read_excel(excel_name, sheet_name = 'Sheet2')

df = df1.append(df2)
```

If not:

```
df1 = pd.read_excel(excel_name, sheet_name = 'Sheet1')
df2 = pd.read_excel(excel_name, sheet_name = 'Sheet2')

# Do whatever you need to transform the dfs

html_str = '<br />'.join([df1.to_html(), df2.to_html()])

with open("file.html", "w") as text_file:
    text_file.write(html_str)

pdf_name = name_of_file + '.pdf'
pdfkit.from_file("file.html", pdf_name)
```

Comment: what does it mean by structure?

Comment: I got an error using the second method for different data structure and I got an error telling me that join only takes in one argument.

Comment: @John, my fault, corrected `join()` method. Please try again.